# Typedef of a structure name to a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, structure, typedef

So A is a structure defined elsewhere. You may ignore the order in which the variables are defined here.
Here, when I use 'B' to define a new variable, what exactly is happening? Is it creating a variable which is a pointer to a structure of type A? I would like as detailed an explanation as possible for what happens when 'typedef struct A *B;' is encountered. Thanks.

```
typedef struct A  *B;

typedef struct {
    B pd_ctx;
} C;

static inline B convert (B handle)
{
    C *ctx;

    ctx = (C *)handle;

    return (ctx->pd_ctx);
}
```

Comment: Please add a language tag.

Comment: "what exactly is happening" you mean besides the aliasing violation? `A` and `C` are unrelated types. Casting from a pointer-to-`A` to a pointer-to-`C` is sketchy-at-best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef struct A  *B;
```

> when I use 'B' to define a new variable, what exactly is happening? Is it creating a variable which is a pointer to a structure of type A?

Yes.  It may be clearer if you look at it like this:

```
typedef struct A*  B;
```

Where the asterisk goes is a matter of style, as with parameters and declarations.

In this case B is not a pointer, it's a pointer type.

Comment: what about 'typedef type_A (*func)(<arguments>);' ?

Comment: That defines `func` as a *function pointer* type; you could then create a `func f`, assign it to a defined function that returns a `type_A` and takes `<arguments>`; if the function is called `foobar`, `func f = foobar`.  You could then call that function with the pointer, `f(<actual arguments>`.

Answer (score 0):

A `typedef` creates no more than a type alias. In other words, it doesn't create a new type, but only an abbreviature or *rewritting* of other type. For example, if you compile the [following code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b75909a7712a8da3):

```
typedef int T1;

void fun1(int) {}
void fun1(T1) {}
```

you will receive a compiler error due to redefinition of function `fun1`.

About the syntax of `typedef`, it has two parts:

```
typedef type_declaration identifier;
```

In your case:

```
 typedef |struct A *|B|;
```

the asterisk isn't a valid character for an identifier. The identifier is only `B`, and the asterisk belong to the type declaration part.

All in sum, `B` is an alias or alternative way of write the type `struct A*`, and of course, `pd_ctx` has type `struct A*`.